# How to install libgtk2.0-dev on NixOS?

Tags: gtk2, nix, nixos

I'm trying to build this application from source: https://gitlab.com/TheFrozenWatchers/LeagueDisplays

Whenever I try running the `make` command, it fails with `'gtk/gtk.h' file not found`. Is there a known way to install libgtk2.0-dev in Nix (the lack of which I'm assuming is the issue here)?

For reference, I'm using these `nix-shell` arguments: `nix-shell -p xorg.libX11 gtk2`. I imagine libgtk2 isn't included in the gtk2 package, but I'm not sure how to actually get the proper headers into the environment for this to work.

Comment: The build process for LeagueDisplays is not Nix friendly because it uses a script to download dependencies and build a Makefile. If you provide a Makefile, I can probably create a Nix expression to build it.

Comment: Here's a Makefile that should work: gist.github.com/pradyuman/33ddf2fb952cf199692e339f35f39ccd. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `shell.nix` you can use:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};

stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
  name = "league-displays-${version}";
  version = "master";

  src = ./.;

  doCheck = true;

  nativeBuildInputs = [ pkgconfig ];
  buildInputs = [ gtk2-x11 clang rapidjson ];

  preBuild = ''
    substituteAllInPlace src/themes_service.h --replace "include/rapidjson/document.h" "rapidjson/document.h"
    substituteInPlace Makefile --replace "pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0" "pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0 RapidJSON"
  '';
}
```

When you enter the shell, instead of `make` run `buildPhase`. That way the `preBuild` step runs and applies some patches.

Even though I've accounted for all known dependencies, the project still doesn't build due to what appears to be some app-specific errors:

```
build flags: SHELL=/nix/store/mcyvp1s45scjkkhyb1m16aqlsb8wr6hs-bash-interactive-4.4-p23/bin/bash
clang++ -O3 -g -w -I. -I./src/ -Wl,-rpath,. -L./bin/ -std=c++14 -Wall -lX11 -lXt -lcef -pthread -lrt -lz `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0 RapidJSON` -I./thirdparty/ -c src/background_daemon.cc
src/background_daemon.cc:23:9: error: unknown type name 'AppConfig'
        AppConfig* cfg = AppConfig::Acquire();
        ^
src/background_daemon.cc:23:26: error: use of undeclared identifier 'AppConfig'
        AppConfig* cfg = AppConfig::Acquire();
                         ^
src/background_daemon.cc:26:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'AppConfig'
        AppConfig::Release();
        ^
src/background_daemon.cc:71:9: error: unknown type name 'AppConfig'
        AppConfig* cfg;
        ^
src/background_daemon.cc:76:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'AppConfig'
            cfg = AppConfig::Acquire();
                  ^
src/background_daemon.cc:110:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'fnvHash'
                unsigned int hash = fnvHash(wp.c_str());
                                    ^
src/background_daemon.cc:133:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'AppConfig'
            AppConfig::Release();
            ^
7 errors generated.
make: *** [Makefile:37: background_daemon.o] Error 1
```